# Nginx resolver per location

Tags: nginx

What are the pros/cons of using a [resolver](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) per location, I found this configuration on a server but my guess is that it not "re-resolving" since the `proxy_pass` is not also using a variable

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://foo_backends;
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
}

location /bar {
    proxy_pass http://bar_backends;
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
}
```

From the docs:

> When you use a variable to specify the domain name in the proxy_pass directive, NGINX re‑resolves the domain name when its TTL expires.

Therefore if I am right the previous configuration could be rewritten like this:

```
resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 10s;

location /foo {
    set $foo_backend_servers foo_backends.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://$foo_backend_servers;
 }

location /bar {
    set $bar_backend_servers bar_backends.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://$bar_backend_servers;
 }
```

Is this correct or there is some trick when using location per location? could it be that by using a resolver per location there is no need to create a variable and pass it to `proxy_pass`?